# Safari 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8) Http/3 on Apple macOS Silicon

Tags: macos, safari, macos-monterey, apple-silicon, http3

Sorry, does anybody observe the issue that http/3 does not work on macOS **Safari 15.5** (17613.2.7.1.8) **Apple Silicon**?
Http/3 is **enabled** in '*Experimental Features*', browser is restarted but this:

```
https://cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace
```

Still shows `http=http/2`

I did the same settings on iPadOS and iOS (v.15.5) and it works fine: Cloudflare shows `http=http/3`

This can be related not only to Silicon (M1/M1 Pro/M1 Max) - I just don't know.

Maybe someone knows why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue anymore for latest Safari.